# Manually populate object generated fom xsd in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Sorry, new to all this...
I have an XSD file which I used to create classes in C# using XSD.exe.
The challenge now is trying to figure out how to manually populate the object so I can then serialise to XML (I won't have a source XML file so I need to manually set the properties via an alternate source).

Below is a sample classes generated from the XSD file. I'm able to set the filesummary and debtor information but no idea how to set the debtorcontact information.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileSummary FileDate="1900-01-01T01:01:01+08:00" OpeningBalance="1" Invoices="1" DebitNotes="1" CreditNotes="1" CashReceipts="1" OtherPositive="1" OtherNegative="1" ClosingBalance="1">
  <Debtor DebtorId="DebtorId2" DebtorName="DebtorName2" ExcludedDebtor="ExcludedDebtor2" CreditLimit="-79228162514264337593543950335" DebtorStatus="DebtorStatus2" TradingTerms="TradingTerms2" OverduePeriod="4294967295" HeadOfficeCode="HeadOfficeCode2" HeadOfficeName="HeadOfficeName2" DebtorCountry="DebtorCountry2" ABN="ABN2" ARBN="ARBN2" ACN="ACN2" LegalName="LegalName2" MainTradingName="MainTradingName2" OtherTradingName="OtherTradingName2">
    <DebtorContact Surname="Surname4" FirstName="FirstName4" OtherNames="OtherNames4" Phone="Phone4" Mobile="Mobile4" Fax="Fax4" Email="Email4" Salutation="Salutation4" JobTitle="JobTitle4" ContactAddress="ContactAddress4" ContactSuburb="ContactSuburb4" ContactCountry="ContactCountry4" ContactState="ContactState4" ContactPostcode="ContactPostcode4" />
    <DebtorContact Surname="Surname5" FirstName="FirstName5" OtherNames="OtherNames5" Phone="Phone5" Mobile="Mobile5" Fax="Fax5" Email="Email5" Salutation="Salutation5" JobTitle="JobTitle5" ContactAddress="ContactAddress5" ContactSuburb="ContactSuburb5" ContactCountry="ContactCountry5" ContactState="ContactState5" ContactPostcode="ContactPostcode5" />
  </Debtor>

    </FileSummary>

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FileSummary {

    private FileSummaryDebtor[] debtorField;

    private System.DateTime fileDateField;

    private decimal openingBalanceField;

    private decimal invoicesField;

    private decimal debitNotesField;

    private decimal creditNotesField;

    private decimal cashReceiptsField;

    private decimal otherPositiveField;

    private decimal otherNegativeField;

    private decimal closingBalanceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Debtor")]
    public FileSummaryDebtor[] Debtor {
        get {
            return this.debtorField;
        }
        set {
            this.debtorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime FileDate {
        get {
            return this.fileDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.fileDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal OpeningBalance {
        get {
            return this.openingBalanceField;
        }
        set {
            this.openingBalanceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Invoices {
        get {
            return this.invoicesField;
        }
        set {
            this.invoicesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal DebitNotes {
        get {
            return this.debitNotesField;
        }
        set {
            this.debitNotesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal CreditNotes {
        get {
            return this.creditNotesField;
        }
        set {
            this.creditNotesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal CashReceipts {
        get {
            return this.cashReceiptsField;
        }
        set {
            this.cashReceiptsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal OtherPositive {
        get {
            return this.otherPositiveField;
        }
        set {
            this.otherPositiveField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal OtherNegative {
        get {
            return this.otherNegativeField;
        }
        set {
            this.otherNegativeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal ClosingBalance {
        get {
            return this.closingBalanceField;
        }
        set {
            this.closingBalanceField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class FileSummaryDebtor {

    private object[] itemsField;

    private string debtorIdField;

    private string debtorNameField;

    private string excludedDebtorField;

    private decimal creditLimitField;

    private string debtorStatusField;

    private string tradingTermsField;

    private uint overduePeriodField;

    private string headOfficeCodeField;

    private string headOfficeNameField;

    private string debtorCountryField;

    private string aBNField;

    private string aRBNField;

    private string aCNField;

    private string legalNameField;

    private string mainTradingNameField;

    private string otherTradingNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DebtorContact", typeof(FileSummaryDebtorDebtorContact))]
      public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DebtorId {
        get {
            return this.debtorIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.debtorIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DebtorName {
        get {
            return this.debtorNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.debtorNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ExcludedDebtor {
        get {
            return this.excludedDebtorField;
        }
        set {
            this.excludedDebtorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal CreditLimit {
        get {
            return this.creditLimitField;
        }
        set {
            this.creditLimitField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DebtorStatus {
        get {
            return this.debtorStatusField;
        }
        set {
            this.debtorStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TradingTerms {
        get {
            return this.tradingTermsField;
        }
        set {
            this.tradingTermsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public uint OverduePeriod {
        get {
            return this.overduePeriodField;
        }
        set {
            this.overduePeriodField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string HeadOfficeCode {
        get {
            return this.headOfficeCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.headOfficeCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string HeadOfficeName {
        get {
            return this.headOfficeNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.headOfficeNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DebtorCountry {
        get {
            return this.debtorCountryField;
        }
        set {
            this.debtorCountryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ABN {
        get {
            return this.aBNField;
        }
        set {
            this.aBNField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ARBN {
        get {
            return this.aRBNField;
        }
        set {
            this.aRBNField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ACN {
        get {
            return this.aCNField;
        }
        set {
            this.aCNField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string LegalName {
        get {
            return this.legalNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.legalNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string MainTradingName {
        get {
            return this.mainTradingNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.mainTradingNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string OtherTradingName {
        get {
            return this.otherTradingNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.otherTradingNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class FileSummaryDebtorDebtorContact {

    private string surnameField;

    private string firstNameField;

    private string otherNamesField;

    private string phoneField;

    private string mobileField;

    private string faxField;

    private string emailField;

    private string salutationField;

    private string jobTitleField;

    private string contactAddressField;

    private string contactSuburbField;

    private string contactCountryField;

    private string contactStateField;

    private string contactPostcodeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Surname {
        get {
            return this.surnameField;
        }
        set {
            this.surnameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return this.firstNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.firstNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string OtherNames {
        get {
            return this.otherNamesField;
        }
        set {
            this.otherNamesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Phone {
        get {
            return this.phoneField;
        }
        set {
            this.phoneField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Mobile {
        get {
            return this.mobileField;
        }
        set {
            this.mobileField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Fax {
        get {
            return this.faxField;
        }
        set {
            this.faxField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Email {
        get {
            return this.emailField;
        }
        set {
            this.emailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Salutation {
        get {
            return this.salutationField;
        }
        set {
            this.salutationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string JobTitle {
        get {
            return this.jobTitleField;
        }
        set {
            this.jobTitleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ContactAddress {
        get {
            return this.contactAddressField;
        }
        set {
            this.contactAddressField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ContactSuburb {
        get {
            return this.contactSuburbField;
        }
        set {
            this.contactSuburbField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ContactCountry {
        get {
            return this.contactCountryField;
        }
        set {
            this.contactCountryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ContactState {
        get {
            return this.contactStateField;
        }
        set {
            this.contactStateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ContactPostcode {
        get {
            return this.contactPostcodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.contactPostcodeField = value;
        }
    }
}







 using System;

namespace CoinsAssetWatchXMLGen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         FileSummary fileSummary = new FileSummary();
        fileSummary.FileDate = DateTime.Today;

        FileSummaryDebtor debtor = new FileSummaryDebtor;

        debtor.DebtorId = "11";
        debtor.DebtorName = "fred";
        debtor.DebtorStatus = "active";
        debtor.ABN = "ABC1234567";            

        fileSummary.Debtor[1] = debtor;

        //how do I associate this following with a debtor for XML??
        FileSummaryDebtorDebtorContact contact = new FileSummaryDebtorDebtorContact();

                }
}
```

}

Comment: The approach I took was to create a dataset using xsd.exe /d to facilitate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took was to create a dataset classes using xsd.exe /d.
Once the data set classes were created

I initially populated the data table as follows just to get a better understanding of the data set structure:

```
 NewDataSet newDataSet = new NewDataSet();           
 newDataSet.ReadXml("FileSummary.xml");
```